# QNetworkReply does not retrieve Content Disposition Header

Tags: qt, header, network-programming, http-headers

```
if(reply->rawHeaderList().contains("Content-Disposition"))
     check=reply->rawHeader("Content-Disposition");
else
     check="no result";
```

The result is “no result” Is this a bug, or is there any work around!

Comment: In response to which `QNetworkReply` signal is that code executed ? Are you sure the server is sending that header and that there is no http redirection (you can test that with "wget -S" or "curl -v") ?

Comment: finished signal of QNetworkAccessManager, method being used is head()